# Please check my proof from supremum infimum topic

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Q : Let A be bounded below and define B$ = \{b \in \mathbb{R} $:b is lower bound for A $\}$
To Show : supB=infA

Proof : Since A is bounded below, lets assume that $a$ is lower bound for A. so $a\in B$. So B is non empty. Also $B=\{ b \in \mathbb{R} : \forall x \in A  (b \leq x)  \}$. So B is bounded above by A. So B has LUB.

Let $SupB=m$
Claim : m is Lower bound for A
If not, then $\exists x \in A (x <m)$. since m=supB. so $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists b \in B (b > m-\epsilon).$Put $ \epsilon = m-x, \exists b \in B (b >x)$, this contradicts the definition of B. So m is lower bound for A.

Let $i$ be other Lower Bound for A. Now $i \in B$. so $i \leq m$. Hence m is infimum of A

Comment: When you say: "This contradicts the fact that all lower bounds of A are $\leq m$", why would you say that? It is correct indeed, i wanna just make sure you know why. The entire proof is correct to me.

Comment: @NoSignals pls check updated answer

Comment: Did you double check? Because what you wrote is incorrect. $a$ is not involved anymore, is $x$ that matters.

Comment: And i must apologize, the fact that all lower bound of A are $\leq m$ is by definition of $m$ and $B$. The fact i wanted to point out is why you get the contradictions in the definition of B.

Comment: Assume $\sup B>\inf A$. Then there exists $b\in B$ such that $\sup B>b>\inf A$. There also exissts $a\in A$ such that $\sup B>b>a>\inf A$. This contradicts your finding that $B$ is bounded above by $A$.

Comment: @KurtG.please verify my proof. Thanks. took me couple of hours to make it

Comment: Will do in a minute. let me just finish this: Conversely, assume $\sup B<\inf A$. This means that there exists $c$ such that $\sup B<c<\inf A$. That is $\forall a\in A$ we have $\sup B<c<a$. This contradicts the definition that $\sup B$ is the supremum of all lower bounds of $A$.

Comment: @SophieClad . Your proof looks correct. You found $x\in A$ and $b\in B$ so that $x<b$. This contradicts the definition of $B$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks a lot.